# How to add OpenStreetMap to my NUXT application

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, openstreetmap, nuxt.js

I want to integrate OpenStreetMap into my NUXT.js application. I am trying to use [this  module](https://github.com/schlunsen/nuxt-leaflet), but I see an empty page after all instructions.

I have created [an issue](https://github.com/schlunsen/nuxt-leaflet/issues/10) on github, but still no answer.

`pages\index.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="map-wrap" style="height: 100%">
    <no-ssr>
      <l-map :zoom=13 :center="[47.413220, -1.219482]">
        <l-tile-layer url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"></l-tile-layer>
        <l-marker :lat-lng="[47.413220, -1.219482]"></l-marker>
      </l-map>
    </no-ssr>
  </div>
</template>
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```
const pkg = require('./package')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',

  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }},
    ]
  },

  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },

  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css'
  ],

  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
    '@/plugins/element-ui'
  ],

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    ['nuxt-leaflet', { /* module options */ }]
  ],
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  */
  axios: {
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
  },

  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: share some code pls

Comment: @Badgy shared, thanks for your response

Comment: whats warnings do u have in console

Comment: Just in case: height is defined as 100% of what?

Comment: @Aldarund, no warnings at all

Comment: @ghybs, thanks a lot! I have changed on 1000px and map is visible now. Stupid mistake :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

just change the style give it width ===>

style="height: 100%; width:500px"